# Consuming MSMQ at a faster speed using multiple threads in asp.net C#

Tags: msmq

I currently have a console application that has this algorithm:

Consume from MSMQ using Peek

Get message out from MSMQ , do sql insert statement

if insert is successful, get message out from MSMQ using Receive()

Using the above consumes 20 messages from MSMQ /sec(20 sql tx per sec), with 1 consume thread

Now , I would want to increase the threads consuming MSMQ , however I discovered that messages get inserted 2 times compared to 1, using peek.

I use Peek() to get the message and process the sql statement initially to deal with server power down suddenly.

If I use Receive() , and the sql statement is not performed , this will result in a loss of data

Please advise.

Comment: Are your queues transactional?

Comment: Peek-then-receive only works for single-threaded systems.

Comment: As Hugh hints, you can avoid losing data on a failed SQL Update by using transactional queues and MSDTC.